# replacing a character in a textbox?

Tags: replace, vb6, keystroke

in `vb6` i would like to be able to detect when the user presses the space key and instead of putting in a space an underscore symbol is used. is that a possibility or am i just being hopeful? i cant seem to quite make out how to do this, i have tried fiddling around with the key-press methods however i don't know of the right code to do this.

```
Private Sub txtbarcode_KeyPress(KeyAscii As Integer)
 if keyascii = vbkeyspace then
 'replace space with underscore
 end if

end sub
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This should work

```
Private Sub txtbarcode_KeyPress(KeyAscii As Integer)
 If KeyAscii = 32 Then
     'replace space with underscore
     KeyAscii = 95
 End If
End Sub
```